# visibility issue in my html css program

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, visibility

The images must be visible when mouse over any square but I have a problem. When mouse over the squares images become visible but at the background we saw a piece of every images. How can I fix that problem?

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.floating-box {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div.float {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin: 100px 200px 100px 240px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

img:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h1>Move Your Mouse Over Squares to See Images</h1>
<div class="float">
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="8.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="9.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `img` is not visible so you can't hover it to show it, you need to make the hover on the box div to show the `img`

```
    img{
         visibility: hidden;
    }
```

```css
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .floating-box{
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        div.float{
            padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
            margin: 100px 200px 100px 240px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
        }
        img{
             visibility: hidden;
        }
        div.floating-box:hover  img{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
           visibility:visible;                      
        }
```

```html
   <h1>Move Your Mouse Over Squares to See Images</h1>
    <div class="float">
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/b77e895475fbc6c52e27b2000ff39604/?default=&amp;s=64" height="32" width="32"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="8.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="9.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use opacity and specify the width and height

```html
<head>

    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .floating-box{
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        div.float{
            padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
            margin: 100px 200px 100px 240px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
        }
         img{
          opacity: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

img:hover{
            opacity:1;                    
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Move Your Mouse Over Squares to See Images</h1>
    <div class="float">
   <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpgg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Greenland_dog_upernavik_2007-06-02_sample.jpg"></div>
 </div>


</body>
```

```
<head>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .floating-box{
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        div.float{
            padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
            margin: 100px 200px 100px 240px;
            border: 1px solid white;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
        }
         img{
          opacity: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }

img:hover{
            opacity:1;                    
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Move Your Mouse Over Squares to See Images</h1>
    <div class="float">
   <div class="floating-box"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="8.jpg"></div>
      <div class="floating-box"><img src="9.jpg"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First answerer mostly correct, but I believe that part of your question was that you see other pieces of the images inside there. To resolve that, you'll want to add width: 100% to each image in order for it to stay inside the container.

So your only changes would be the following:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.floating-box {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/* Just add the width control here to the image to avoid leaks */
.floating-box img {
  width:100%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
div.float {
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin: 100px 200px 100px 240px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
/* Make the hover on the floating-box instead of on img */
.floating-box:hover img {
  width:100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h1>Move Your Mouse Over Squares to See Images</h1>
<div class="float">
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/A-gray-kitten-meowing.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="3.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="4.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="5.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="6.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="7.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="8.jpg"></div>
  <div class="floating-box"><img src="9.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

And then for the hover itself the same, but hover applied to the box, not the image (.floating-box:hover img).